# MySQL 8 - Slow select when order by combined with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble understanding my options for how to optimize this specific query. Looking online, I find various resources, but all for queries that don't match my particular one. From what I could gather, it's very hard to optimize a query when you have an order by combined with a limit.

My usecase is that i would like to have a paginated datatable that displayed the latest records first.

The query in question is the following (to fetch 10 latest records):

```sql
select
    `xyz`.*
from
    xyz
where
    `xyz`.`fk_campaign_id` = 95870
    and `xyz`.`voided` = 0
order by
    `registration_id` desc
limit 10 offset 0
```

& table DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
  `registration_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_campaign_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_customer_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  ... other fields ...
  `voided` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`registration_id`),
  .... ~12 other indexes ...
  KEY `activityOverview` (`fk_campaign_id`,`voided`,`registration_id` DESC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280614594 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;
```

The explain on the query mentioned gives me the following:

```
"id","select_type","table","partitions","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","filtered","Extra"
1,SIMPLE,db_campaign_registration,,index,"getTop5,winners,findByPage,foreignKeyExistingCheck,limitReachedIp,byCampaign,emailExistingCheck,getAll,getAllDated,activityOverview",PRIMARY,"4",,1626,0.65,Using where; Backward index scan
```

As you can see it says it only hits 1626 rows. But, when i execute it - then it takes 200+ seconds to run.

I'm doing this to fetch data for a datatable that is to display the latest 10 records. I also have pagination that allows one to navigate pages (only able to go to next page, not last or make any big jumps).

To further help with getting the full picture I've put together a dbfiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/Jc_K68rj - this fiddle does not have the same results as my table. But i suspect this is because of the data size that I'm having with my table.

The table in question has 120GB data and 39.000.000 active records. I already have an index put in that should cover the query and allow it to fetch the data fast. Am i completely missing something here?

Comment: `I already have an index put in` ... what is that index and can you add it to your question?

Comment: Why do you need to sort the entire table to just take 10 rows? Use MIN or MAX

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's part of the DDL.

KEY `activityOverview` (`fk_campaign_id`,`voided`,`registration_id` DESC)

@JonasMetzler It's for a datatable. To display the 10 latest records for a specific campaign. I'l lupdate the question to reflect this.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Also updated the query. I see i had mistaken for the SQL preview put the order by as ASC and not DESC.

Comment: fk_campaign_id` = 95870 and `xyz`.`voided` = 0, how many records you have for this condition?

Comment: @aatwork 500.000 - i was expecting it to use the index activityOverview that was tailored for this. But it doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The "10 latest records for a specific campaign" can be found without sorting half a million rows. Just use for example MAX -10. Order by can if necessary then be applied on those 10 rows instead of all others, too.

Comment: @JonasMetzler This is unfortunately not possible for me since -10 would match records that doesn't respect the where clause.

Comment: I think you don't unverstand what I mean. You apply some conditions within your query. Half a million entries satisfy these conditions. Now you are sorting that half a million entries which is not required. You don't want to sort them, but to get the latest 10 of them. This can be done with id >= max id - 10. From any result that you order can instead just be taken the max or min value. This will very likely be faster.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I understand this. But max id - 10 would match the 10 rows that came before the max id. But these 10 rows could be rows that doesn't match the condition. Seeing as the registration_id is incremental those 9 other rows may be on other fk_campaign_id and not the one put as a condition for the query. So this would only really work if i had a table per data set, so i didn't have any condition at all.

Comment: No, you don't. Any result set that can be ordered can also be used to build max and min value. Ordering is nothing else. Might be needed to create a sub query or a partition clause, but taking the last or the first 10 rows using MAX or MIN is always possible. If it wouldn't, you couldn't use order by, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249622/discussion-between-danniehansenweb-and-jonas-metzler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution goes something like this:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM ( SELECT registration_id 
             FROM xyz
            where  `xyz`.`fk_campaign_id` = 95870
              and  `xyz`.`voided` = 0
            order by  `registration_id` desc
            limit  10 offset 0 ) AS a
    JOIN xyz AS b USING (registration_id)
    order by  `registration_id` desc;
```

Explanation:

- The derived table (subquery) will use the 'best' query without any extra prompting -- since it is "covering".
- That will deliver 10 ids
- Then 10 JOINs to the table to get `xyz.*`
- A derived table is unordered, so the `ORDER BY` does need repeating.

That's tricking the Optimizer into doing what it should have done anyway.

(Again, I encourage getting rid of any indexes that are prefixes of the the 3-column, optimal, index discussed.)

Comment: Hi Rick,

I've manually attempted to test this specific query against various data sets. Looks to be doing the trick! I would never have guessed this to be more performant since in essence the outcome should be the same. But i guess the selecting of the fields are what makes the big difference to the optimizer?

I'm going to attempt pushing this and seeing how it plays out in QA/Production. I will get back with my findings.

Comment: @danniehansenweb - Having a "covering" index is part of the 'secret sauce'.  Another part is avoiding the fetching of "*" columns (especially if `TEXT` is involved), only to throw away all but 10 rows.

Comment: Hi Rick,

We've now deployed our solution and it appears to have resolved all of our issues. Really appreciate your help. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
KEY `activityOverview` (`fk_campaign_id`,`voided`,`registration_id` DESC)
```

is optimal.  (Nearly as good is the same index, but without the `DESC`).

Let's see the other indexes.  I strongly suspect that there is at least one index that is a prefix of that index.  Remove it/them.  The Optimizer sometimes gets confused and picks the "smaller" index instead of the "better index.

Here's a technique for seeing whether it manages to read only 10 rows instead of most of the table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: Hello Rick. We're actually already today enforcing the use of the index using the USE INDEX(activityOverview) syntax. The explain on the query with this shows that it uses the index. So i don't think this is the case here. Looking at the explain then without the use index() it says it hits 1600 rows and with the use index() it says 500.000 rows. Neither of them are fast. Both takes 200+ seconds to run.